# Passing a user-selected currency into DDUnitConverter

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, user-input

I have this code that uses [`DDUnitConverter`](https://github.com/davedelong/DDUnitConverter) for currency conversion.

```
#import "DDUnitConverter.h"
#import "DDCurrencyUnitConverter.h"

- (void) convertCurrency {

  DDUnitConverter *converter = [DDUnitConverter currencyUnitConverter];

  NSNumber *from = [NSNumber numberWithInt:42];

  NSNumber *to = [converter convertNumber:from fromUnit:DDCurrencyUnitUKPoundSterling toUnit:DDCurrencyUnitUSDollar];

  NSLog(@"new value: %@", to);
}
```

I want to set the `fromUnit:` and `toUnit:` arguments based on the user's selection. How should I do that?

Answer (score 6):

`DDCurrencyUnit` is an `enum` (enumerated type). If you use a picker view for your user to pick a currency, you can use the selected row index for `fromUnit` and `toUnit`, as long as the rows in the picker are in the same order as they are in the enumeration.

For example, `DDCurrencyUnitEuro` is 0, `DDCurrencyUnitJapaneseYen` is 1, `DDCurrencyUnitUKPoundSterling` is 2 and so on. So if the first row of your picker view is "Euro", your second is "Japanese Yen", your third "UK Sterling" and so on, then the selected row index will correspond to the unit parameter.

Your example above is equivalent to

```
NSNumber *to = [converter convertNumber:from fromUnit:2 toUnit:3];
```

Comment: thanks. please give a demo for how to set  "fromUnit:2 toUnit:3"  .  And how to use picker.

Comment: Look at the documentation for UIPickerView.

Comment: if you have any Sample Code like above concept. please attach me.  –  Michael L

Comment: Do a search for a tutorial on UIPickerView - I am sure you will find something useful.

Comment: i find it... Thank u so much... :)